# KeyBindings in JavaFX 2

Tags: event-handling, javafx

How to use KeyBindings in JFX 2? I need to reassign Enter key from carrige returning to my own function, and for carrige returning assign CTRL+ENTER

I've tried this way, but still it makes a new line.

```
messageArea.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                sendMessage();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If want to prevent the default behavior of event you are filtering, you need to [consume](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/event/Event.html#consume%28%29) it.

There are numerous kinds of KeyEvents, you may want to filter on [KeyEvent.ANY](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#ANY) instead of just `KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED` and consume them all.

Comment: thanx, consume method did the job.

Answer (score 9):

As an addition to jewelsea's answer. To control key combinations use:

```
if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER) && event.isControlDown()) { // CTRL + ENTER
    messageArea.setText(messageArea.getText() + "\n");
}
```

in your handler.