# Javafx2: Is there a way to know if an ActionEvent occurred due to a mouseclick?

Tags: javafx-2, mouseclick-event, actionevent

Is there a way to know if an ActionEvent occurred due to a mouseclick?

Comment: Please give more information, do you want to check each mouseclick event in a custom method (event handler or filter)?

Comment: I have a context menu on which I have a few menuitems placed. The problem I have is that whenever the context menu is active(i.e. displayed) and enter is pressed on the keyboard, the first menu item gets fired. I want to block that by checking if the event was fired by a mouse click or not.

Comment: Check this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440099/keybindings-in-javafx-2
You need to consume the event to stop the propagation of your KeyEvent